# How to diagonalize $D_1U^\dagger D_2U$ with unitary $U$ and real diagonal $D_{1,2}$

Tags: matrices, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

Is there a trick to diagonalize the following expression
$$D_1U^\dagger D_2U$$
such that
$$D_1U^\dagger D_2U=V^\dagger D\,V$$
where $U$ is unitary and $D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagonal and real?

Comment: If you put $D_1=I$, then that is the general form of a self-adjoint matrix. I would not expect to find a method that works better than the standard methods.

Comment: @user161825 With standard methods you mean: Evaluating the roots of the characteristic polynom,... I thougt one might get the eigenvalues directly out of the entries of the diagonal matricies.

Comment: I see what you are getting at. If I understand correctly, you basically want to know the spectrum of $TS$ in terms of $T$ and $S$ if $T$ and $S$ are self-adjoint (you may assume for free that $T$ is diagonal). I would not expect a neat solution, but maybe someone more knowledgeable than me will prove me wrong.

Comment: Are you only interested in the spectrum (eigenvalues)? Is there some specific information than you wish to extract?

Comment: No, I need the unitary matrix which diagonalizes, too.

Comment: Nobody is interested in this issue :(

Comment: Is $D_1$ or $D_2$ positive semi-definite? Does $V$ satisfy any conditions?